# SearchDisplayControler, UILabel stacking after selection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to implement a searchDisplayController but I've a problem. Once I filtered the cell and when I selected the cell remaining I get a strange stack of text :

http://postimage.org/image/4fswe8t8n/

It's like having all my cell in one.

So there's my cellForRowAtIndexPath method :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MFriendCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil)  {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

if(tableView == self.tableView) {
    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:201];
    nameLabel.text = [self.allItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    UILabel *labelName = [ [UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0.0, 150.0, 43.0) ];
    labelName.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell addSubview:labelName];
}
return cell;
}
```

And my filter :

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText
                         scope:(NSString*)scope
{
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];

self.searchResults = [self.allItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

if you need anything else just ask :)

Comment: this is because you are setting a new label on previous label

Comment: Is it because my logic is bad or I should just add something to check if there are already a label?

Comment: you want to add different label or set your text to previous label

Comment: Change the text, but it's ok I changed the way I was manipuling my UILabel and now it's working just fine ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make label in you tableView like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MFriendCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:201];

    if(tableView == self.tableView)
    {
       nameLabel.text = [self.allItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    }

    else if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        labelName.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `nameLabel` in cell same like `labelName` see the code bellow..

```
if(tableView == self.tableView) {
    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:201];
    nameLabel.text = [self.allItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell addSubview:nameLabel]; ///YOU ARE Not add This Lable so Add this lable also
}
else if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    UILabel *labelName = [ [UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0.0, 150.0, 43.0) ];
    labelName.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell addSubview:labelName];
}
```

here in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method u just take value of `self.allItems` array instead of `self.searchResults` array WHEN you are in `searchResultTableView`

try this code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;{
     if(tableView == self.tableView) {
         NSLog("\n Normal Table View Selected cell ==> %@",[self.allItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    }
    else if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
           NSLog("\n Search TableView Selected cell ==> %@",[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];);


    }
}
```

and also in `numberOfRowsInSection` method set row like bellow...

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(tableView == self.tableView) {
             return [self.allItems count];

        }
        else{
               return [self.searchResults count];    
        }
}
```

i hope this help you...

Comment: @BaNz you add [cell addSubview:labelName]; but not add same like[cell addSubview:nameLabel]; in if(tableView == self.tableView) { this condition dude.. try it..

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me but I think like Rajneesh071 said, it's because I'm adding multiple time a label to the subview of the cell.

Comment: yes dude but here also possible to problem which i tell and also here you see the latest label with your title so must required to add current label on cell as a subview right dude??